# Progressive web apps with Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

We have a Hybrid App build using **Cordova/Ionic** hosted on **PlayStore** and **IStore** .

Since the app is running inside of a browser. Can i then host this specific "wwww" folder to my web server ?

The hybrid app uses cordova to access camera to take photos and upload to server.

Can i convert this hybrid app with little modification to run when accessed through an **url** to work like my **App** hosted in the Playstore / iStore ?

Probably with **Progressive Web Apps** ?

Answer (score -1):

Yes simply referring to www folder works.

Comment: How do i make the cordova part of it to work ? I use couple of cordova api which access ccamera/location etc. ?

Comment: I am not sure for Camera but location is part of latest browser.  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Answer (score -1):

I tried to convert progressive web app to cordova (for web push notifications which are not available on iOS yet). It works very well. You must just adjust some elements replacing cordova plugins with html5. You can access camera, gps...